# 100 year old door help

Tags: paint, repainting

Paint came off 100 year old dining room door and the paint can’t be matched. What do I do, and how?

[image]

Comment: Mount a mirror? Strip and repaint the whole thing?

Comment: If repainting, make sure you clean the surface well.  Probably what happen the last time it was painted, there was dust/dirt/oil left in that section.

Comment: I am sure that the paint could be matched.  But even then you have to paint the whole door.  Have you tried taking a chip to your paint shop ?

Comment: What do you _want_ to do? Repaint it? Strip it and put on a clear coat finish so you can see what is, likely, beautiful wood under the paint? Replace it completely? This is a _very_ broad question. TBH, if it were my door, I'd take the door to a restorer and have them dip it to remove all the paint. You've probably got oak or walnut or mahogany under that paint and it's just languishing. Even if it's just cruddy pine, after a dip, it'll be in the perfect condition for a new, high quality paint job.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "magic cure".

The door will have to be scraped and sanded at the edges of the pealed paint.
then the entire door or the panel will have to be painted.

You may be able to get a large enough sample chip to take to a paint store and have paint matched so close you may never tell if you just paint the center panel.